# Should I negotiate a raise with my boss, even if I'm not sure I will accept a better job offer?

Tags: new-job, job-change, job-offer

I have a job offer from another company, with considerably more money than in my current job. The main motivation for accepting this new job is money, because I've been having health problems recently and I have been spending a lot, I'm afraid I'll be broke shortly if I don't find another source of income.

I like my current job a lot, and I don't like that much what I'll be doing on my new job. I was hoping to speak with my boss, he is very open, but I don't want to look unprofessional, and let him know my motivation to moving to this new job is mostly financial because of my health situation. Would this look unprofessional if at the end I decide to stay? Also I would be a huge loss for the company, I'm one of the oldest employee and all the technology of the company was designed by me. We have been always understaffed so basically I'm the only one who know how everything works.

Comment: "Discuss" for what reason -- negotiating a raise? Giving notice? Other?

Comment: negotiating a raise

Answer (score 7):

Ask him for more money.  Don't tell him there's an offer on the table.  Tell him you've been getting inquiries for positions paying the offered salary, and say that you love your job but are having trouble meeting expenses.  If you are so valuable, they should pay you.

Comment: 'should' maybe replace with 'will'? They are under no obligation.

Comment: Agree especially with the "getting inquiries for positions paying the offered salary" - I did just this and got what I needed by saying "i've been invited to apply to and although I'm happy, I need to seriously consider it ..."

Comment: Agree with Kevin. Better to ask your existing company hinting "getting inquiries for positions paying the offered salary". If they are smart enough they will take favorable step else you know what to do. Also, they can't argue that you have not asked or hinted them in advance.

Comment: @JanDoggen: By "should pay", I'm stating that it is prudent for employers to pay valued employees the market wage.  "Will pay" would be a prediction.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if they don't pay you then (as far as they know) you aren't that valuable to them.